# spring batch recommended tables indexes

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-batch

I'm looking for recommended indexes for spring batch tables,
specially when using the API:

```
jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
```

any one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the JdbcJobExecutionDao implementation for the SimpleJobExplorer then the only columns involved in the query for the where clause are as follows:

> JOB_EXECUTION.JOB_INSTANCE_ID
>
> JOB_EXECUTION.END_TIME
>
> JOB_INSTANCE.JOB_INSTANCE_ID
>
> JOB_INSTANCE.JOB_NAME

And the order by is using: JOB_EXECUTION.JOB_EXECUTION_ID

You can take a look at the source for JdbcJobExecutionDao for the actual queries. As for your question about what indexes to create. JOB_INSTANCE_ID seems to be a good candidate in this case.